# Single value rollup from a set of values in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

I have a Fruit array whihc has named fruits object which has a status property the status of each fruit needs to rollup to the fruits status

Here is a sample:

```
const fruits = [
    {id: 'apple', status: 'good'},
    {id: 'orange', status: 'inprogress'},
    {id: 'kiwi', status: 'error'}
]
```

based on the status property if all the fruits status is the same , the fruits.status  = the common property.

- if any one of the status is error, the Fruits status is error
- if only good and in progress , fruits.status is in progress

How can we do this  in es6 ?

I tried

```
function getFruitsStatus(fruitarray) {
    const types = new Set(fruitarray.map(({status}) => status));
    types.forEach(function(value) {
      console.log(value);
   });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Set/has) to see if an element is contained in your set:

```js
const fruits = [
    {id: 'apple', status: 'good'},
    {id: 'orange', status: 'inprogress'},
    {id: 'kiwi', status: 'error'}
]

const goods = [{status: 'good'}]

const progress = [{status: 'good'}, {status: 'inprogress'}]

function getFruitsStatus(fruitarray) {
    const types = new Set( fruitarray.map(({status}) => status) )
    if (types.has('error')) throw new Error('Bad fruit')
    if (types.has('inprogress')) return 'inprogress'
    return 'good'
   
}

console.log(getFruitsStatus(goods))
console.log(getFruitsStatus(progress))
console.log(getFruitsStatus(fruits))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do

```
function getFruitsStatus(fruitarray) {
  return fruitarray.reduce((status, item) => {
    if (status === 'error' || item.status ==='error') return 'error';
    if (status === 'inprogress') return 'inprogress';

    return item.status;
  }, 'good');
```